# Html.EditorFor inside java script

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am learning ASP MVC and I try do form, and when you click the button on the form, I want to add some content to div in this form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
     <input type="button" value="Click to edit address" onclick="@String.Format("addAddress()")" />
    <div id='divResult'>

        Here I want to add new conntent after click button.

    </div>
    <div>
}
```

My Java Script function does't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addAddress() {
            $('#divResult').replaceWith("@Html.EditorFor(m => m.User.HomeAddress)");
        }
</script>
```

Can anyone help me? I want to fill my User (model.User) object and post filled to server, but Athe address you can fill only after click button, because it has a lot of field to be filled, but address is not necessary.

Comment: Why just add it, hide (with css), and show when user presses the button?  Theoreticaly, your code should work any error? You should try also wrap it with `Html.Raw`: `@Html.Raw(Html.EditorFor(...))`.

Comment: Is your script placed in cshtml?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Click to edit address" onclick="addAddress()" />
    <div id='divResult' hidden='hidden' >
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.User.HomeAddress)
    </div>
</div>
}
```

-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addAddress() {
        $('#divResult').show();
    }
</script>
```